# What is B2 space in topology?

Tags: general-topology

In James Munkres's book there is "There is no retraction of $B^2$. onto $S^1$". What is "$B^2$ space" here? It also says "the fundamental group of $B^2$ is trivial" so does $B^2$ mean $R^2$ - the plane? But why is it called $B^2$? Search Bing for "topology B2 space" "topology B*B space" gives no result and I don't want to scan the whole book for $B^2$ so I ask it here.

Comment: Maybe $B_n$ is the unit ball in Euclidean $n$-space, so $B_2$ is the unit disk in the plane.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the first edition of Munkres' *Topology*.

On page 342, exercise 6 is "Show there is no retraction $r:B^2\to S^1$, where $B^2$ is the unit  ball in $R^2.$"

Comment: In my version it is Theorem 55.2

Answer (score 0):

Common standard spaces (where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the standard Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$):

$\Bbb B^n = \{x \in \Bbb R^n\mid \|x\|_2 \le 1\}$ is the $n$-dimensional unit “ball” (hence the $B$) and its boundary

$\Bbb S^{n-1} = \{x \in \Bbb R^n: \|x\|_2=1\}$, the $n-1$-dimensional “sphere” (hence the $S$).

In the plane $n=2$ these reduce to the unit disk and the unit circle. $B^n, S^n$ (without the blackboard typeface) are also used. $P^n$ is used for projective spaces.